How can I use coroutines to dynamically wait for time in while
I have encapsulated a while that waits for 8 hours to end. I need to repeat the task in it until the time reaches 8 hours. How can I make while wait for my task to end before starting the next cycle, instead of a fixed delay time?
fun startPeriodicTask(timeout: Long, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit) {
         periodicTask = viewModelScope.launcher {
            while (dataService.timeConfigData.runTime.value!!.toLong() < dataService.timeConfigData.timeEnd.value!!.toLong()) {
                withTimeout(timeout) {
                    // 执行任务
                    XLog.v("startPeriodicTask run block")
                    block()
                }
                delay(timeout)
            }
        }
    }

    vm.startPeriodicTask(2000) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    mVibrator?.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(1000, 255))
    } else {
    mVibrator?.vibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 2000), 1)
    }
    }

My understanding is that this is not feasible, because the coroutine is a recursive process, so when I suspend it, I can't wait, and the main thread is blocked.
================================================================
I modified it according to broot's method. In fact, I didn't wait, but just started the coroutine task, which caused while to be repeated countless times in a short time. I don't know if my modification is correct.
fun startPeriodicTask(timeout: Long, block:() -> Unit) {
//        periodicTask = viewModelScope.launcher {
    while (dataService.timeConfigData.runTime.value!!.toLong() < 
    dataService.timeConfigData.timeEnd.value!!.toLong()) {
        XLog.v("startPeriodicTask run block")
        block()
//                delay(timeout)
//            }
    }
}

        

vm.dataService.
testConfigData.isSpeakerSwitch.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        if (it) {
            vm.startPeriodicTask(25000) {
                play {
                    XLog.d("play end")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun play(onCompleted: () -> Unit) {
    stop()
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(requireContext(), R.raw.testsignal)
    mMediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener {
        stop()
        onCompleted()
    })
    mMediaPlayer?.start()
}



From the description I'm not exactly sure what you need. If you need to wait for 8 hours, use delay. If you need to wait for a suspend function to finish, just call it - it returns when it finishes. Anyway, waiting for 8 hours doesn't seem feasible in Android. Applications don't live for so long.

Coroutines are not the right solution for such long tasks on Android.

@broot As shown in the second code, I did a vibration test here and used delay(2000) as a delay, and then looped the vibration test in while infinitely until 8 hours. We don't care whether it will exit or not. I want to make while dynamically wait for the task I set instead of a fixed delay(2000). For example, I want to vibrate randomly for 5 seconds, 6 seconds, or make a network request instead of vibration, etc. I need the block() method to complete before the next loop of while

You should make the block suspend for the time the task is running and then you don't need at all to delay - you just call it in a loop.

@broot If I allow it directly, it will block the UI thread and cause ANR. My startPeriodicTask is implemented in viewmodel, and calling startPeriodicTask is implemented in Fragment

Suspending a coroutine doesn't block the thread.

@broot If block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit is used, it will only start the coroutine without waiting for the coroutine to complete. If there is no delay, while will immediately start the next loop. If suspend and withTimeout are removed, the thread will be blocked. What I want is how to not block the thread and let while wait for my task to complete, instead of fixing the delay time. This is a bit difficult for me.

And I already told you how you could solve the problem. Suspend the block. Looking at your current example, you could move delay from the startPeriodicTask to after you call vibrate (so move from the first code snippet to the second). If I understand your case correctly, this very simple change will do exactly what you need. You can do a similar thing with other cases than vibrate.

@broot I tried the method you provided, but it didn't wait for completion correctly. Instead, it started the loop directly, and started a task each time.

I solved the problem again. I used coroutine waiting in the block to solve it. Thanks to @broot
    fun startPeriodicTask(timeout: Long, block:suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit) {
     periodicTask = viewModelScope.launcher {
        while (dataService.timeConfigData.runTime.value!!.toLong() < dataService.timeConfigData.timeEnd.value!!.toLong()) {
                // 执行任务
                XLog.v("startPeriodicTask run block")
                block()
        }
    }
}


vm.dataService.testConfigData.isSpeakerSwitch.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        if (it) {
            vm.startPeriodicTask(25000) {
                    play {
                        XLog.d("play end")
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun play(onCompleted: () -> Unit): Boolean {
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { suspend ->
        stop()
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(requireContext(), R.raw.testsignal)
        mMediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener {
            stop()
            onCompleted()
            suspend.resume(true) {
                XLog.d("play end")
            }
        })
        mMediaPlayer?.start()
    }

}

